# sudo yum install <package-name> is giving weird error on AWS Linux ec2 (SyntaxError: invalid syntax)

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, installation, yum

Machine details:

Cloud: AWS

OS: Linux ip-10-196-64-140.eu-west-1.compute.internal 4.14.209-160.335.amzn2.x86_64 #1 SMP Wed Dec 2 23:31:46 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Error details:

```
[ec2-user@ip-<hostip> ~]$ sudo yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless
  File "/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: The command is fine. Did you press Ctr+C to stop it?

Comment: Thanks @ Marcin for quick response, no i don't need to , as soon as i type in command it exits with above error :(

Comment: Is it new instance? Maybe you did something, installing some software, changing default settings, to it and "broke" yum somehow?

Comment: no, this is quite an old instance, used by multiple users. your prediction can be correct. but I cannot decommission this machine as it is integrated into CI/CD pipeline.

Comment: If this is some production instance, you can make copy of it (AMI), if possible, and try to fix it on copy first. You could try calling yum directly `/usr/share/yum-cli/yummain.py install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless` and skip `yum` wrapper.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried to **reproduce the issue**, and it fails when you run yum with **python3** instead of python2:

```
python3 /usr/bin/yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless
  File "/usr/bin/yum", line 30
    except KeyboardInterrupt, e:
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

You should **use python2**, not python3 for yum:

```
python2 /usr/bin/yum install java-11-amazon-corretto-headless
```

It seems that in your instance **default python** version was changed to python3.

Comment: Your recommendation worked like a charm, to resolve it permanently this is what i did: "sudo  ln -sfn /usr/bin/python2 /usr/bin/python" Thanks a lot @ Marcin

Comment: @AmitMeena No problem. Glad it worked out. If you change it back, then maybe something else will break.